# How can i use Javascript to play a CSS animation at a specific video time?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to be able to use javascript to play an animated image element at a specific point of time in a video, I have the animation ready, I just want to know how to make it play at a point of time in the video. Basically like an event when the script reads the video element is at a specific time.

I heard the `.currentTime` property could be used to implement this, but I'm stumped on how to get it to work. I want it to play only once, and if the user scrubs the timeline or replays the video it will play the animation again at that time.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

video {
  width: 600px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animation {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 500px;
  top: 100px;
  animation-name: fling;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes fling {
  0% {left: 500px;top:100px;visibility:visible;}
  20% {left: 800px;top:10px;transform:rotate(360deg);}
  40% {left: 1100px;top:100px;transform:rotate(-180deg);}
  42% {visibility:hidden;}
  100% {visibility: hidden;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center>
    <div class="inner">
      <video controls autoplay>
        <source src="missile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <img class="animation" src="https://paulgo.io/image_proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FFQ_yFiLXMAAJmW9%3Fformat%3Dpng%26name%3Dlarge&h=d8af5114b1bd85e1d64353e43be2f4c1ea2edfc90479d4e7a12270ee9974616e">
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Plese edit your question to include the content of `js/fling.js` in the snippet so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.setInterval() to check the current time every second like this and add the animation class to the image:

```
let video = document.getElementById("videoID");
let timeToAnimate = 100;
let i = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (video.currentTime >= timeToAnimate) {
        document.getElementById("imageID").classList.add('animation');
    }
},100);
```

You would also have to change the HTML slightly by removing the animation class from the image and adding ids to the video and image:

```
<video controls autoplay id="videoID">
    <source src="missile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<img id="imageID" src="https://paulgo.io/image_proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FFQ_yFiLXMAAJmW9%3Fformat%3Dpng%26name%3Dlarge&h=d8af5114b1bd85e1d64353e43be2f4c1ea2edfc90479d4e7a12270ee9974616e">
```

To make this work every time the user replays the video, you can use the seeked event:

```
video.addEventListener('seeked', () => {
    document.getElementById("imageID").classList.remove('animation');
})
```